# how can I use twice grocery_crud_file_upload_allow_file_types

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, grocery-crud

I have a problem, I have in my database two fields, in both I save the link of a file, in one, an image, and in the other a file (PDF), I need, when I am adding or editing, when I select the Upload file, allow only the specific type of file. I do this:

```
//--- (BEGIN) Upload single file ---//

  $this->load->config('grocery_crud');
  $this->config->set_item('grocery_crud_file_upload_allow_file_types', 'pdf'); 
  $this->crud->set_field_upload('file', 'assets/files/'); 

//--- (end) Upload single file ---//

//--- (BEGIN) Upload single image ---//

 $this->load->config('grocery_crud'); 
 $this->config->set_item('grocery_crud_file_upload_allow_file_types', 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png'); 
 $this->crud->set_field_upload('image', 'assets/image'); 

//--- (END) Upload single image ---//
```

But, when I insert, the first thing is the PDF, and it saids that can not be upload, and when I comment `'grocery_crud_file_upload_allow_file_types', 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png`  it works, but I need restrict the types.

thanks in advance.

Comment: $this->config->set_item('grocery_crud_file_upload_allow_file_types', 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png|pdf', just once!!

Comment: yes, I do that, but what hapend if I try to put an imagen where its supouse to be a PDF file? That is what I do not want to happend